# How to use dependable ddl in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two dropdownlists, the second has data that completely depends on the first one, here are samples of the ddl's:

```
<select name="tipochip" class="form-control" required ng-model="formvendas.model.idchipotipoprod">
<option ng-repeat="produto in vendas.produtos" value="{{$index}}">{{produto.Descricao}}</option>
</select>
```

the second one that dosent work:

```
<select name="tipochip2" class="form-control"
required
ng-disabled="formvendas.model.idchipotipoprod==undefined || formvendas.model.idchipotipoprod==null"
ng-model="formvendas.model.idchipotipo">

<option ng-repeat="promo in vendas.produtos[formVendas.model.idchipotipoprod].kids" value=" {{promo.IDChipTipo}}">{{promo.Descricao}}</option> </select>
```

i now the problem is related with ng-repeat, but i dont now other way of doing it using angular. I need a way to dinamically insert options in the second ddl after the first is changed

Here is an example of the data that i have so you can understand my problem:

```
{"prods": [
        {
            "IDChipTipo": 1,
            "Descricao": "ddl1 data",
            "kids": [
                {
                    "IDChipTipo": 2,
                    "Descricao": "ddl2 data first",

                },
                {
                    "IDChipTipo": 3,
                    "Descricao": "ddl2 data second",

                },
                {
                    "IDChipTipo": 4,
                    "Descricao": "ddl2 data third",

                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "IDChipTipo": 200,
            "Descricao": "some other ddl1 data",
            "kids": null
        }
    ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example of how to do this here: http://plnkr.co/edit/KA9OH6qzyiZoaehMv2NW?p=preview

I showed 3 ways to do it:

1. working the way you were doing it using ng-repeat.
2. using ng-options, which ends up making the value be the selected
   object.
3. using scope variables to keep the logic simpler

Oddly I'm not sure what I changed for your way to make it work. It must have just been a typo or something I guess. I'm not going to take the time to figure that you, but I'd be interested to hear what it was if you do.

I prefer #3 because it's more **testable** and easier to debug. It's so nice to being able to set breakpoints in the browser and debug that the child list is being created properly.

Here are snippets from the 3rd way of solving this.

controller:

```
$scope.getKidOptions = function() {
  var selectedProduct = $scope.formvendas.model.selectedProduct;
  if (selectedProduct) {
    return selectedProduct.kids;
  }

  return []
};
```

html:

```
<select name="tipochip-os" class="form-control" required
        ng-model="formvendas.model.selectedProduct"
        ng-options="p.Descricao for p in products track by p.IDChipTipo"></select>

<select name="tipochip-os2" class="form-control"
        required
        ng-disabled="!formvendas.model.selectedProduct"
        ng-model="formvendas.model.selectedKid"
        ng-options="k.Descricao for k in getKidOptions()"></select>
```